Restoring SQL Server 2014 database leads to junk characters for tamil data
While migrating data from one SQL Server to the other I have access to just the .BAK file. I tried restoring it in my SQL Server 2014 Express.
While the restore was successful, the data inside the tables is now showing some junk characters. When I try to create a new row in the same table in Tamil language as an nvarchar, it does insert properly and I am able to view the data in tamil language properly. Just that the rows which were restored are having junk characters.
Here is the snippet of the data that has been restored. Can someone let me know what is it that I am missing. Quite new to having data other than English in the database. So not sure if there are any Collation settings that needs to be tweaked in order for the db to support regional language support during a restore.


FYI, SQL Server 2014 reaches end of life on  Tuesday you really should be looking to upgrade. Considering you're using Express, there's no good reasons to not be using a fully supported release, let alone one only in extended support.

The rows must have been incorrect to start with (ie inserted incorrectly). Backup/restore will not do this.
